# TypeScript: combine behavior of type and implementation

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
type MyClassType = {
  state: 0;
  data: {
    p1: boolean;
  };
} | {
  state: 1;
  data: {
    p2: boolean;
  };
} | {
  state: 2;
  data: {
    p3: boolean;
  };
}

class MyClassImplementation {
  state = 0;
  data = {
    p1: true
  };
}

export const MyClass = MyClassImplementation as {
  new (): MyClassType;
}

function a(c: MyClassImplementation) {
  // works fine, but without completion I want
  if (c.state === 1) {
    c.data.p2; // error: Property 'p2' does not exist on type '{ p1: boolean; }'.
  }
}
```

The following code works the way I want:

```js
function b(c: MyClassType) {
  if (c.state === 1) {
    c.data.p2; // works fine
  }
}
```

The following code gives me an error: 'MyClass' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyClass'?

```js
function c(c: MyClass) {
}
```

Is there a way to combine behavior of `MyClassType` and `MyClassImplementation`? I want to have right suggestions and create new instances using single entity (`MyClass`)? So I don't want to export `MyClassType` and `MyClassImplementation`, only `MyClass`.

Comment: This feels like a bit of an edge case usage, but one suggestion is perhaps doing `c: typeof MyClass`, would that help you out?

Comment: Just export a type named `MyClass` also that is equivalent to `MyClassType` (or rename `MyClassType` to `MyClass` and export that).

Comment: @jcalz, it really works, but how about `export default`? Will it work?

Comment: @jcalz, I tried `export default` and it works too. Can you answer instead of comment?

Comment: Sure, but the question doesn't mention `export default` anywhere so the answer won't either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to rename `MyClassType` to `MyClass` and `export` that as well as your `MyClass` value:

```
export type MyClass = { /* your union of things */ }

export const MyClass = MyClassImplementation as {
  new(): MyClass;
}
```

This will allow those who import `MyClass` to get both the named constructor value and the named instance type, similarly to how `class` names and types work:

```
import { MyClass } from 'mymodule';
const c: MyClass = new MyClass(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgLID2AJgK4bIGFFLwYhRRIUCeAwhy4BJMDEaRgAFxBSAllWB4WrJFBlTkAXiQAGANwrWNWSCQ6Cq1TACMALiRSATnQhGiAX0OqP+IxAAPGConKUdeGEoBIW4LdzUNCAcDeJMZB0srIlsHACMqKkYQYG8rLyMPJAAfZSz1WSSkG1LVNJAM+OyAJjyCopL48p9q2qt6zQculuNTDqzsgGZewohi6c9p338gkLD4RXUeaM5Yo8ET0XEISQ0FJU5R1WAIAHcACgBKBz5zrk2-TwApAAemBSDkYl2eDOMSQlQAZk4qGAkAByMC8MC0BgQVEsfbAQ7wb7YxgAOh+sJ0zxePFJEApxy4n0MLHhdGA8HkiiQuTexLp9HJlJOH0e4PhSH5ZPG2i0OhsYsyqngZLaZJgUxBYJeIQA1tx4XJnhUWFsPEA)